# $P(X > cY)$ where $X,Y$ are gaussian distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I believe that as long as $X,Y$ have zero mean, then regardless of what their variance is, and for any constant $c$, $P(X > cY)$ should always be $0.5$. It's easier to visualize if you think about the bivariate distribution of $X$ and $Y$ projected onto the $xy$-plane. It'll be either a perfect circle if the two variables have the same variance, or an ellipse with differing variances. Any line with any  slope that passes through the origin will cut the area of the bivariate pdf in half, hence the probability of 0.5.

Is this correct?

Is this true regardless if $X,Y$ are independent or not?

Comment: It is true if they have a joint bivariate normal distribution, even if they are correlated, but I suspect there will be counterexamples where they each have normal distributions and the dependence is more complicated

Comment: It might be easily proved using simple integration for both independent case and dependent case.

Comment: @Henry Isn't the joint distribution of *any* 2 normal random variables always bivariate normal?

Comment: @student010101 No.  For that you need all linear combinations to be normal, which is not necessarily the case.  For example, $Y=X$ if $\lvert X\rvert>c$ and $Y=-X$ otherwise, then $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal for any $X\sim N(0,1)$ but $Y\sim N(0,1)$ too.

Comment: @user10354138 Ah I see. How do you determine if a linear combination of X and Y is normal?

Comment: Just take $X=Y$ to understand your question about independence.

Comment: @Michael Ahh yeah that'd $P(X = Y > Y) = 0$ and here $X=Y$ are dependent. So it does make a difference.

Comment: @Michael Is there a a case where $X,Y$ are dependent and $P(X > cY) = 0.5$ for any $c$?

Comment: Take $Y=X+N$ for $X, N$ independent Gaussian $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Another case when $X$ and $Y$ are independent but your inequality fails is when $X,Y$ are Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 0, so $P[X=0]=P[Y=0]=1$. Then $P[0>0]=0$.

Comment: @Michael Ooo right. The single point pdf.

Comment: @Michael I do not understand why your $Y=X+N$ for $X,N$ independent Gaussian $N(0,1)$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @Henry That was a response for my question "Is there a case where $X,Y$ are dependent and $P(X > cY) = 0.5$ for any $c$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring extreme cases such as variances of $0$ or correlation of $\pm1$, it is true that $P(X > cY) =\frac12$ if $X$ and $Y$ have a joint [bivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), even if they are correlated.  You get something like this, and by symmetry half the distribution is above the red line.

[image]

So any counterexample needs to break the symmetry.  Here is an example using R, where only about $37\%$ of the joint distribution is above the red line, achieved by twisting points on the left hand side below the line without changing the marginal distributions.

```
set.seed(2021)
cases <- 10^5
X <- rnorm(cases)
Y <- ifelse(X>=0, X, -qnorm(3/2-pnorm(abs(X))))*24/25 + rnorm(cases)*7/25
mean(Y > 2*X)
# 0.36701

plot(X,Y, pch=".")
abline(h=0); abline(v=0); abline(0,2, col="red")
```

[image]

and to check the two distributions are indeed normally distributed, the simulated empirical densities for $X$ (in blue) and $Y$ (in red) are shown over the theoretical density (in black)

```
curve(dnorm, from=-4, to=4)
points(density(X), col="blue", type="l")
points(density(Y), col="red" , type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there something general that can be said for when correlated $X$ and $Y$ "breaks symmetry?"

Comment: There are probably bounds, though I do not see immediately how to approach finding them

Comment: I think I'm confused after seeing Michael's counterexample using $Y = X$ and your plot. If you set $Y = X$, then their correlation is 1. My understanding is correlation simply rotates the ellipse about the origin, so a $X = cY$ line should still cut the ellipse in half regardless of the magnitude of the correlation? But when I look at the term $P(X > cY)$ and with $P(Y > cY)$, it would seem we would reach a contradiction for any $c \geq 1$.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm visualizing the $Y = X$ case incorrectly. The pdf becomes undefined for cases where the correlation is $\pm 1$

Comment: The $Y=X$ case is extreme and there is no density. The test $Y>X$ then becomes unhelpful

Comment: In your second example, with the broken symmetry, it appears that the correlation is constant for $x \geq 0$, but non-constant for $x < 0$?

Comment: @student010101 - that does not quite make sense in formal terms, but yes - I took the $x,y$ data for the first example (which was bivariate with $\rho=\frac{24}{25}$ across the whole distribution) and then twisted it when $x <0$ for the second example